# What is the opaque field in HTTP Digest Access Authentication used for?

Tags: authentication

Is the `opaque` field really used for anything? It is specified in [the RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), but is not implemented in Apache. Also, the RFC does not state a reason for having `opaque`, it is only mentioned as a value that should be returned to the sender.

I'm thinking that it may be used to prove that the response-opaque came from a request that was made earlier in time.

Comment: "The opaque data is useful for transporting state information around"
what do you mean by "state information"? can you please clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you drill into the [An Extension to HTTP : Digest Access Authentication RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2069), they define opaque as follows:

> opaque:
> A string of data, specified by the server, which should be
> returned by the client unchanged.  It is recommended that this
> string be base64 or hexadecimal data.  This field is a
> "quoted-string" as specified in [section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2069#section-2.2) of the HTTP/1.1
> specification.

which is pretty close to what you saw in the RFC you mentioned, further in the get into details a little more

> The opaque data is useful for transporting state information around.
> For example, a server could be responsible for authenticating content
> which actually sits on another server.  The first 401 response would
> include a domain field which includes the URI on the second server,
> and the opaque field for specifying state information.  The client
> will retry the request, at which time the server may respond with a
> 301/302 redirection, pointing to the URI on the second server.  The
> client will follow the redirection, and pass the same Authorization
> header, including the  data which the second server may
> require.

Comment: Good eye! Surprising that the old RFC is more detailed..